# Придаточное определительное и причастный оборот

Tags: согласование, определения, причастный-оборот, придаточное-предложение

**«Он стал разбираться в документальной и юридической стороне финансовых вопросов, с которой у меня всегда были проблемы и важность которой я недооценивал».**

**«В них фиксировалась сумма вложенного капитала и право владельца на долю прибыли, соответствующую его вкладу»**

Так правильно говорить?
Очевидно, что «которой» относится к слову «стороне», а «соответствующую» — к слову «долю» т.к. только они стоят в таком же роде, числе и падеже, хоть и после них еще есть другие слова.

И вообще, общий вопрос. Местоимение «который» в придаточном предложении и причастие в причастном обороте в общем случае должны относиться к последнему слову в главном предложений или к тому, которое стоит в том же роде и числе, и оно может быть не последним, например иметь после себя несогласованное определение. Т.е. главное, чтобы не возникало путаницы со смыслом: к чему именно относится последующее местоимение или причастие (чтобы только то слово, которое нужно, стояло в том же роде и числе, что и местоимение «который» или причастие). Для причастия, я так понял, важен ещё один и тот же падеж.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, так можно писать. Вы все правильно понимаете. И еще, причастию, как глагольной форме, присущи значения времени, вида, залога. И все это также должно учитываться при согласовании причастия с определеяемым словом.

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm) пишет:

> Часть книг, **предназначенная** для выставки, уже получена (получены все книги, предназначенные для выставки). – Часть книг, **предназначенных** для выставки, уже получена (получены не все книги, предназначенные для выставки). Такие варианты согласования встречаются в тех случаях, когда причастный оборот определяет не отдельное слово, а словосочетание. Ср. также: количество электроэнергии, потребляемое... (подчеркивается количественная сторона) – количество электроэнергии, потребляемой... (характеризуется объект, о части которого идет речь); две тысячи рублей, взятых взаймы – десять тысяч рублей, взятые у сестры (Л. Толстой).
>
> В некоторых случаях причастные обороты, подобно придаточным определительным предложениям, допускают двоякую соотнесенность, на почве чего возникает двузначность предложения, например: «Заявление председателя комитета, занимающегося этими вопросами» (занимается председатель или комитет?). Возможные варианты правки: Заявление, сделанное председателем комитета, занимающимся этими вопросами – ...занимающегося этими вопросами.

Comment: То есть допустима даже такая оторванность от определяемого слова, как предложении: "Это была дочь одного из очень влиятельных государев, которую я в этом городе встречал не раз"?

Comment: Слово *государев* отвечает на вопрос чей?; оно лишено смысла в данном предложении.

Comment: Прошу прощения за опечатку. Имелось в виду "государей".

Comment: Смысл этой фразы кажется мне странным, но формально все в ней правильно.

Comment: _Две тысячи рублей, взятых взаймы – десять тысяч рублей, взятые у сестры_ (Л. Толстой). А вот здесь я что-то не очень понял — в чём разница?

Comment: "Две тысячи **рублей, взятых взаймы**  — подчеркивается,  что деньги взяты взаймы, "**десять тысяч** рублей, **взятые** у сестры" —  подчеркивается взятая сумма.